# EF doesn't update navigation property in database

Tags: entity-framework

I have two classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public TenderType TenderType { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class TenderType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When editing `Foo` class, when I change `TenderType` property and use this code:

```
_db.Entry(tender).State = EntityState.Modified;
_db.SaveChanges();
```

everything seems to work and my context will refresh with new values, but only properties like `Subject` has been changed in database! And `TenderType` still is unchanged in database (not in context)!

Even after calling `db.SaveChange()` if I execute a fetch Linq query on `Foo`, context returned a record with the new values! But in database, `TenderType` still has the old values.

What is this Entity Framework behavior and why?

How can I fix this?

(I use EF 5).

Comment: Can you show how you **modify/edit** the instance of your `Foo` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found my answer by myself.
after `_db.SaveChanges();` i do a `_db=new Context();` and Re-appointment of values, then `_db.SaveChanges();` did work.
but i did't get the memo!

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you need to tell EF to `Include<>()` your underlying objects. The reason **Subject** works is b/c its not a custom class. *I have not tried this or anything, but I think this is what you need to do. If this doesnt work, let me know and i'll remove this incorrect answer*

```
var fooEntity = _db.Set<Foo>().Include(o => o.TenderType);
fooEntity.State = EntityState.Modified;
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Since I often have many properties (which are custom classes) I often create extension methods for my DB entity to help me with this, and why not also throw in a delegate for filtering data directly using a lambda expression..

```
public static IQueryable<Foo> AllFoo(this MyDBContext context, Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> predicate = null)
{
    if (predicate == null)
        predicate = o => o != null; 

     return context.Foo
        .Where(predicate)
        .Include(o => o.TenderType);
}
```

now...

```
var fooEntity = _db.AllFoo(o => o.TenderType == TenderTypes.Type1).FirstOrDefault();
fooEntity.TenderType = TenderTypes.Type2;
_db.SaveChanges();
```